# Evaluate and save Argument variable value during function definition?

Tags: r

Consider this function `plus_x`:

```r
y <- 1

plus_x <- function(input, x = y){
  return(input + x)
}
```

here the `y` default-value for `x` is evaluated during the function call.
If I change `y` later on, I am also changing the functions behaviour.

```r
y <- 1

plus_x <- function(input, x = y){
  return(input + x)
}

y <-10

plus_x(1)
# > 11
```

Is there a way to "cement" the value for `y` to the state it was during the function definition?

Target:

```r
y <- 1

plus_x <- function(input, x = y){
  # y is now always 1
  return(input + x)
}

y <-10

plus_x(1)
# > 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the function using `as.function` so that the default value is evaluated at the time of function construction.

```r
y <- 1

plus_x <- as.function(list(input = NULL, x = y, quote({
  return(input + x)
  })))

plus_x(1)
#> [1] 2

y <-10

plus_x(1)
#> [1] 2
```

Answer (score 3):

**1) local** Surround the function with a `local` that saves `y` locally:

```
y <- 1

plus_x <- local({
  y <- y
  function(input, x = y) input + x
})

y <-10
plus_x(1)
## [1] 2
```

**2) generator** Another approach is to create a generator function.  This has the advantage that multiple different functions with different y values could be easily defined.  Look at `demo("scoping", package = "base")` for more examples of using scoping.

```
gen <- function(y) {
  force(y)
  function(input, x = y) input + x
}

y <- 1
plus_1 <- gen(y)
y <-10
plus_1(1)
## [1] 2

y <- 2
plus_2 <- gen(y)
y <- 10
plus_2(1)
## [1] 3
```